# What are the array keys of $content that can be hidden?

Tags: 7, theming

I see that with drupal 7 theming, we can mark elements of the `$content` array as hidden.

From http://drupal.org/update/themes/6/7 :

```
  <?php
    // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
    hide($content['comments']);
    hide($content['links']);
    print render($content);
  ?>
```

What other keys always exist? Or if they are dynamically generated, what is the best way to check the hideable content elements?

Thanks

**Edit**
With the devel module enabled, I found that the information I was looking for roughly corresponds to the information found at the location `/node/your_nid/devel/render`.
Or using PHP directly, `dprint_r(array_keys($content));`

Comment: Instead you can do  `<?php print render($content['important_stuff']); ?>`  isn't it ?

Comment: @Sivaji Yes you could just render specific elements, it is the equivalent functionality as hiding some. My question was what `'important_stuff'` keys exist and how to find them.

Comment: Modules mentioned in the answers below will help in this regard. Perhaps you can simply use `print_r()` to get the list of available keys and print only the required stuffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is dynamical, all modules can add new elements.

Install http://drupal.org/project/devel and then use dpm($content); Note that when you do this inside a page, you will probably only see it after another reload.

Answer (score 2):

Install [Devel Themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) too...